# UItextview formatting with UIImageView

Tags: ios, uitextview, core-text

In my app i need to formate text and image as i show in ScreenShot.
[image]

How can i do this type of formatting? Should i go with CoreText? if yes How can i do that?

I have gone through example of Raywenderlich here is Link - [Core Text Example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text)

but it is different than what i want. So can anyone Help me to solve this?

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) - I've been using it for a long time now in my apps and it can handle either attributed strings or HTML (or both). You can embed images and links, and is all been working quite well for me for a year now. The code is supported (ie bugs get fixed).

This class was designed specifically for applications like yours. In his demo app he has "War and Peace" so you can see it handles huge tasks!

Comment: hi thanx for Reply.I m totally new to deal with Core Text. But Example u provided is really awesome. Let me go with this. thanx David.

Comment: Hi David. But the DTCoreText is not editable. Is there any other tools to edit both text and image?

Comment: You can purchase a license from Cocoanetics for their expanded framework that does permit editing. This is the only framework I know of that does support edits. I'm sure you'd like a free one but I know of no such project - but you should at least look yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not exactly what are you asking for but I would suggest to go with a `UIWebView`!

Within the `UIWebView` you can show HTML code which would be really easy to format like your example shown in your question.

Comment: I have thought to go with UIWebView. but i have a problem there.Here My text is coming from server, if it has "<p>" tag in some starting line, then the Line of text will be override to that image in UIWebView.

Comment: Can't you simply remove all `<p>` tags before displaying the text within the `UIWebView`?

Comment: Should't be a problem with the right css style definition. Could you please post an example of your HTML encoded text?